# Which distribution to choose when modeling variance of a normal distribution?

Tags: time-series, bayesian, pymc

I have a simple time series model where there is a single hidden variable $\lambda_t$ which changes over time: $\lambda_{t+1} \sim \mathcal{N}(\lambda_t,\sigma)$. The $\lambda_t$ is then used as a parameter for a Poisson distribution from which observations are made.

Since $\sigma$ here is also unknown, what distribution should be used to model it?

Comment: The way you wrote it $\sigma$ seems to be fixed, so why would you care about its distribution?

Comment: Why would it make sense for $\lambda$ be normal? $\lambda$ is necessarily non-negative, while a normal (necessarily) has some of its probability below 0. If you model a Poisson with small $\lambda$ you're going to be dealing with negative $\lambda$.

Comment: Forllowing @Glen_b, you should use a truncated-normal or a truncated Cauchy or a log-normal on the $\lambda_t$'s. And I would opt for an improper prior $\pi(\sigma)=1/\sigma$. But note that there is no unique choice for a prior distribution and thus you are entitled to any prior you feel reflects your prior information or lack thereof.

Comment: ... or a gamma, perhaps

Comment: @RichardHardy I don't care about the distribution of $\sigma$, but it is an unknown parameter, so I thought it needs to be modelled.

Comment: This model makes no sense. Maybe you better describe your process, then folks can help you come up with a more sensible model.

Comment: I'm totally confused on the setup of this problem, but you don't need to assume a distribution to estimate the value of $\sigma$. What's wrong with just using the sample standard deviation? Also keep in mind that the mean and variance are the same for the Poisson RV.

Comment: @wcampbell: $\lambda$ is a hidden variable (as stated in the OP) so I am not sure whether its sample standard variation can be observed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, $\lambda$ is fed to Poisson as its mean. I do not quite understand why you use a Gaussian to model its dynamics as a Gaussian includes negative support. Why not, say, pass $\lambda$ through some link function e.g., $\exp()$ and feed $\exp(\lambda)$ to Poisson ?

You said

> I don't care about the distribution of σ, but it is an unknown parameter, so I thought it needs to be modelled.

So why don't you treat $\sigma$ as a parameter and determine it in M-step of EM algorithm ? No prior distribution is needed. If you really want a prior distribution over it, a Gamma distribution might be a good choice as its domain is positive real.